# how to return nested equals with primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to render  the "name". I need to get the ID from tblPatientDrugAllergy and it will match the ID in tblPatientDrugAllergyReaction.

The ID in `PatientDrugAllergyReaction` should tie to the `tblAllergyReaction` and from there should return the `Name`. I got the first where but the and is returning everything that is one instead of tiering. What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

```
select tblAllergyReaction.name 
 From tblPatientDrugAllergyReaction s, tblPatientDrugAllergy t, tblAllergyReaction u
  where tblPatientDrugAllergy.ID=tblPatientDrugAllergyReaction.ID and 
  s.PatientDrugAllergyID = u.ID
```

Comment: What rdms are you using? mysql? sql-server,etc?

Comment: Did you mention 4 tables? or did you mean to say that the ID in     tblPatientDrugAllergyReaction should tie to the tblAllergyReaction?

Comment: yes that is what I mean and we are using mssql

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be you were aliasing the tables, however didn't use the alias

```
select u.name 
From tblPatientDrugAllergyReaction s, tblPatientDrugAllergy t, tblAllergyReaction u
where t.ID=s.ID and 
    s.PatientDrugAllergyID = u.ID
```

Comment: Oops. I didn't use the alias for the select. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand exactly what you want. Next time please include sample tables/data and desired output. That will make it easier for someone to give a correct response.

If I understand it correctly, the problem seems to be that you are joining `tblAllergyReaction`  to `tblPatientDrugAllergyReaction` on `PatientDrugAllergyID = ID`, which probably isn't correct.

Try this instead:

```
  select ar.name 
  from tblPatientDrugAllergyReaction AS pdar,
       tblPatientDrugAllergy AS pda t, 
       tblAllergyReaction AS ar u
   where pda.ID=pdar.PatientDrugAllergyID 
   and pdar.ID = ar.ID
```

Comment: Didn't work   tblPatientDrugAllergy.ID  will Join on tblpatientDRugAllergyReaction.ID.   Then in the that same table it will locate the field patientDrugAllergyID  and join that to tblAllergeyReaction.ID and will return the Name from tblAllergyReaction table.

Comment: Well, it would seem that having a column named `ID` which is a primary key in some of the tables, and a foreign key in other tables is _**a bad idea**_, and leads to confusion.

Comment: Yeah I know but they were already there and I have to work with what I have- LOL

Comment: Well, as I said, I can't see your data, so I'm only guessing. Try breaking the query into two and running each part separately, carefully checking that it is producing the correct result from each. Then put them back together. I can't see anything wrong with the basic structure of your query, so I still suspect that you are joining on the wrong columns.